# Since you can declare a copy constructor in two ways in C++ which is the right way?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Say you have the following class:

```
class Person{
    string name;
    int age;
    int niNo;

public:
    Person(const string & _name, const int & _age, const int & ni) : name(_name), age(_age), niNo(ni) {}

    string getName() const{
        return name;
    }

    int getAge() const{
        return age;
    }

    int getNi() const{
        return niNo;
    }

    bool operator==(const Person &p){
        return name == p.getName() && age == p.getAge() && niNo == p.getNi();
    }
```

And then you can define the copy constructor as follows:

```
    Person (const Person &other){
        name = other.name;
        age = other.age;
        niNo = other.age;
    }
```

or like this

```
    Person (const Person &other) : name(other.getName()), age(other.getAge()), niNo(other.getNi()) {}
```

Which is the best way to do it? Or does it not matter?

Comment: The question says you can "declare" them two different ways but both declarations you demonstrate are the same `Person (const Person &);`

Comment: I recommend you read `Effective C++`, it makes exactly that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the two ways you described, I would strongly recommend using the initializer list.

When control enters the body of your constructor, standards dictate that the object is fully initialized at that time, therefore all its members must be initialized as well. What your first example does is that it initializes all the members in some default way and then assigns to them later.

This is potentially ineffective if one of the class members is a huge object, and impossible to do if a member cannot be initialized without parameters, i. e. the member is a `const`, a reference, or is a class with no default constructor.

In that case, you must use the initializer list to customize the initialization process. Initializer list syntax can also be used to delegate construction (C++11) and initialize base classes.

Answer (score 3):

As your class is trivially copy constructable, the best way is in C++11 :

```
Person (const Person &other) = default;
```

Otherwise, the second one is he better, because there is no default init and affection as in the first one.

Comment: Or better still, don't declare it at all. Why add unneeded clutter?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: the reason to add clutter (which doesn't always apply) is that it's easier to read explicit code saying that there's a copy constructor, than it is to look through the class checking whether it contains anything that would inhibit generation of a copy constructor.

Comment: @SteveJessop: True; if your class is already so cluttered that it's not obvious, then extra clutter might do more good than harm. Perhaps it's better to avoid clutter in the first place, though.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I don't think that having a base class or data member whose copyability is non-obvious constitutes "clutter". But certainly, if you remove useless clutter like bases and data members of class type from your classes, then they'll be a lot easier to read ;-p Alternatively you can of course just document the class as CopyConstructible, it's not like we were helpless prior to C++11.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well, I do. It's a matter of opinion though, and not worth arguing about.

Answer (score 2):

The second is more efficient. In the first, the member `name` is first default constructed and then assigned.

Answer (score 2):

In general (not just for copy constructors) it's better to initialise members directly in the initialiser list, as your second example does. The first example default-initialises them, then reassigns them. This is potentially less efficient, and won't work for all types: it requires that they be default-initialisable and copy-assignable, while direct initialisation doesn't.

In this case, where you just want a simple member-wise copy, don't declare a copy constructor at all. The implicitly generated one will do the right thing, and will be less error-prone since it doesn't need updating if you add new members.

Answer (score 2):

One important aspect to add.
If one of your private data members is const let's say `name`

```
class Person{
   const string name;
    int age;
    int niNo;
...
```

You have no option and you must initialize name in the constructor initializer list!

If it is constant it has been default constructed before entering the body of the constructor and you can't redefine it as it constant...so there you must use the initializer list